# Is 大元【おおもと】the right word here? Or should it be 大本【おおもと】?

Tags: kanji, compounds

Is 大元 a mistake in this quotation, or is it acceptable?

本音【ほんね】を言【い】えないことは、多【おお】くの人【ひと】の悩【なや】みの大元【おおもと】にある

*The inability to express one's true feelings is at the root of many people's problems.*

https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASQ5564JNQ4SPTIL009.html?iref=comtop_Topnews2_03

Comment: This site claims the two are largely interchangeable: https://chigai.site/8848/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see them as the same word, just written different ways. This is in contrast to homonyms like 雲/蜘蛛 for くも. Both kanji forms 大本 and 大元 are valid. Hiragana (おおもと) is not too unreasonable, too.

大本 is also the name of a Shinto sect started one century ago. That may be why some people avoid writing that way when they mean the more general term.

Answer (score 1):

本 and 元 essentially mean the same thing, as can be seen in the [entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%9C%AC_%28%E3%82%82%E3%81%A8%29/#jn-219563) in デジタル大辞泉. So 大本 and 大元 should be interchangeable and 大元 is acceptable, although most dictionaries seem to have only [大本](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%A4%A7%E6%9C%AC_%28%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8A%E3%82%82%E3%81%A8%29/#jn-29619).